# Sort formula with two different columns - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of data that I'd like to sort first by the timestamp column (C), and then sort by last name (E). So I'm trying to get a descending time order, but then within each calendar day, the data should be sorted alphabetically.

I need a formula, not the sort or filter option, so the form is dynamic and can continually update as more responses come in.

This last part might be a pipedream, but here's a bonus challenge: Once the data sorts, I'd like to be able to have a checkbox next to their name (A), and if more data comes in and the formula moves their name, could that checkbox stay with their name and move with them?

Here's what I've got:
[Google Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjNwP.jpg)

P.S. I know just enough about formulas to get myself into trouble, but not enough to get out. I think I need an arrayformula, but that is a bit beyond my capabilities. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

looks like job for `SORT` so for example:

```
=SORT(A3:G; 3; 1; 5; 1)
```

where you sort first the 3rd column in ascending order (or otherwise called date-descending order in your case) and then 5th column in ascending alphabetical order

bonus answer:

> if more data comes in and the formula moves their name, could that checkbox stay with their name and move with them?

absolutely not possible. further addition of data can scramble whole your dataset but in theory, if new data will come with timestamp, after you sort it, it will always go down the line so if you won't change/edit anything within incoming data, this will be possible to sustain.